# Should I keep WKWebView in UICollectionView forever to avoid reloading?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, wkwebview

I have some `WKWebViews` that load some HTML, and it takes a few seconds to load. I embed `WKWebView` in my `UICollectionViewCell`. So when the user scrolls the `UICollectionView`, the cell may be reused, but I don't want to load the HTML again when the user scrolls back.

Is it a good idea to keep the `WKWebView` forever even if they are off-screen? I don't want them to reload every time because that will affect user experience. However, I do worry about memory usage.

What is the best solution to tackle this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What’s the order of magnitude for the amount of items in the collectionview?

Comment: The maximum is 200 - 500 items. So O(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reuse happens:

- you should cancel the previous `URL` loading on the `webView` that is being reused; (1)
- you should start loading of the new `URL` from scratch; (2)

  - load contents of URL over network (2.1)
  - load DOM into the web view (2.2)

There are several ways to optimise this process:

- avoid (1), i.e. avoid reuse - then your app gets into off-screen views and, most probably, will be killed due to memory pressure
- try to avoid (2.1) - you can cache the data of `URL` before feeding it to the web view, and get the cached data when it's present. Or, alternatively, add a capability to send [cache control headers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) on the server side, then `WKWebView` will do caching automatically.
- try to optimise (2.2) - you can reuse the same `WKProcessPool` among all the `webView`s that you create, by assigning the same `WKProcessPool` instance to your `WKWebViewConfiguration`. `WKWebView` is the lightweight wrapper that proxies the input and output through the inter-process communication with the Web View Content Process. By reusing the process pool, you will achieve some level of reuse of the content processes that are created by each webView.